# Understanding LANG on macOS

Tags: postgresql, macos, zsh, iterm2

This is the error message I do get, when I tried to create a cluster:

```sh
> pg_createcluster 12 main
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 12/main ...
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/var/lib/postgresql/12/main --auth-local peer --auth-host md5
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "ogirginc".
This user must also own the server process.

initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
Error: initdb failed
```

My understanding was with the "[Set locale variables automatically](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html)" option checked on iTerm2, I should have a `LANG` variable available on path, either from `AppleLocale`'s value

```sh
> defaults read -g AppleLocale
en_TR
```

or Mac's "Language & Region" preferences, which are set as:

1. English (UK)
2. Turksih

However, that's not the case:

```sh
> locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

When I list `/usr/share/locale`, I can see locale files with additional languages are present too.

I never had set these before but then I wasn't using [postgresql-common](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql). What should I set for both `LANG` and `LC_ALL` in my `.zshrc`, as there isn't a `en_TR` after checking with `locale -a`?

**System Summary**

- macOS Catalina - 10.15.5
- iTerm - 3.3.11
- zsh - 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)

Comment: Without being too familiar with MacOS, `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` looks invalid. Try a valid value, like `C.UTF-8` or `en_TR.UTF-8` or any UTF-8 locale that is present in the `locale -a` output.

Comment: I haven't tried with UTF-8 as I also thought that should not work. I just exported `US` to my shell created a cluster. Do it work? Yes. Is it the best practice? No idea. ‍♂️

Comment: @originc: Since the locale behaves so many aspects of the programs, you really should take care and setting the variables depending on your needs, even on a per-script base. For instance, I **do** have defaults set in .zshrc, I don't hesitate to change them even just in certain scripts. BTW, what is `en_TR` supposed to mean? I would understand `tr_TR` or  `en_GB` (this is what I usually have), but your en_TR seems to address a language environment of a "english-speaking group in Turkey or Northern Cyprus".